# Date from datepicker dialog not getting set in textview of the popup android

Tags: android

My question is in onDateSet method, how do i retrieve the selected date from the datepicker dialog on my textview field which is an activity embedded on popup. I get the nullpointer exception for:
  ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinner_date)).setText("Date"+year);

**DatePickerFragment.java**

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
    implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}


public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
     Log.w("DatePicker", "Date = " + year);
  ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.spinner_date)).setText("Date"+year);
}
```

}

**In MainActivity.java**

```
     public void createVideoEvent(View arg0) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater
            = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
            .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_event_create,          null);
    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
            popupView,
           400,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    View new_event_button = (View) findViewById(R.id.button);
    popupWindow.showAsDropDown(new_event_button);

   dateSpinner = (TextView) popupView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_date);

    View.OnTouchListener Spinner_OnTouch = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                showDatePickerDialog(v);
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
    View.OnKeyListener Spinner_OnKey = new View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER) {
                showDatePickerDialog(v);
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    };

    dateSpinner.setOnTouchListener(Spinner_OnTouch);
    dateSpinner.setOnKeyListener(Spinner_OnKey);
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("cccc, MMMM dd, yyyy", Locale.US);
    dateSpinner.setText(sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime()));

}
public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Date");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you want to create an interface within the DialogFragment and send the data to the interface.  Next you want to implement the listener for that interface within the activity. Inside that listener you will set the text. There should not be any issues, but if there are let me know and I will try and help.

**DatePickerFragment** First you want to create an interface in this class, then implement it in the activity.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.widget.DatePicker;

import java.util.Calendar;


public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
        implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }


    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        mCallbacks.setTextDate(year, month, day);
    }

    /**
     * Interface to communicate to the parent activity (MainActivity.java)
     */
    private FragmentCallbacks mCallbacks;

    public interface FragmentCallbacks {
        void setTextDate(int year, int month, int day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) { // Attach it to the activity
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (FragmentCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement Fragment One.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() { // Remove the listener
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity**  Make sure you call  implements DatePickerFragment.FragmentCallbacks after extending the class!

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

// Make sure you implement the listener in the DatePickerFragment()
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerFragment.FragmentCallbacks {
    private TextView dateSpinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Removed the touch listeners for this example to make it simple.
        // Show dialog on start for this example
        showDatePickerDialog();

        dateSpinner = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spinner_date);
    }

    // Changed it to getSupportFragmentManager(),
    // You might need to change yours back to getFragmentManager()
    public void showDatePickerDialog() {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Date");
    }

    // The interface listener created in the DatePickerFragment()
    @Override
    public void setTextDate(int year, int month, int day) {
        dateSpinner.setText("Date Year: " + year);
    }
}
```